# JQuery layered hovered styles

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a row in which upon being hovered a tooltip appears. This tooltip has a slight overlap onto the row. If this overlap is being targeted, the opacity of the tooltip switches because JQuery isn't sure which one to read. I am looking to prevent this switching to occur.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tooltip_hover").hover(function(e){
    $('.tooltip2').css("opacity", "1");
  },function(e){
    $('.tooltip2').css("opacity", "0");
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip_hover {
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
}
.tooltip2 {
  left: 178px;
  top: 555px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  border: #b5b5b5 solid 2px;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #bebebe;
}
.tooltip2:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  top: -13.5px;
  left: 12%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
}
.tooltip_hover:hover {
  background:#FFE100;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tooltip2:hover{
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class=" tooltip_hover" >
    <td>
      <a>Nothing</a>
    </td>
    <td >Nothing</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div class="tooltip2">
  <div style="padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:15px"> </div>
</div>
```

Recap: When the cursor is over the tooltip and the row, the tooltip switches opacity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to interact with the tooltip itself, you can add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the `.tooltip2` class. This sets the element to ignore mouse events, and mouse events will target the elements under it - the `tr` in your case.

```
.tooltip2 {
    pointer-events: none,
    left: 178px;
    top: 555px;
    width: 550px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    border: #b5b5b5 solid 2px;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  transition:  opacity 0.5s;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #bebebe;
}
```